# Get data of user ID in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Say I have a database with two tables one has:

```
id
name
email
password
```

And the other has the brands they stored in the database:

```
id
brand_id
brand_quantity
```

How can I make sure that if 'Alex' logs into his account he'll be able to access his info, edit, add, delete only and not someone else's?
The PDO script that I wrote till now can modify, edit, delete all info whether it was Alex's info or John's or any. How do I surpass that?

**Script:**

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }
}
     if (isset($_POST['sub']) == 1) {
        $id2 = $_POST['id2'];
        $qty2 = $_POST['qty2'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT brand_qty FROM brands WHERE brand_id = :id2");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id2', $id2);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
            $s = $v - $qty2;
            if ($s >= 3) {
                echo "<script>alert('Almost out of stock!');</script>";
            }
            $sth = "UPDATE brands SET brand_qty='$s' WHERE brand_id = '$id2'";
            $conn->exec($sth);

            echo "<script>alert('New record successfully updated.')</script>";
        }
```

Tables:
members table image

[image]

their brands and their quantity table

[image]

Comment: Add Alex id to you sql scripts

Comment: You have to define relation between brand and user table.

Comment: But it's going to be for multiple users (example: 300 users), it's virtually impossible to add all of their ID manually. Right?

Comment: @mr-engineer, can you post an example of how to define a relation between both tables?

Comment: Add a column in brands table and store user ID there. Then you can make conditional queries.

Comment: Refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: could you share the table schema with some example data as there is little to work with above

Answer (score -1):

First define relation between your tables. For example add `userid` in your brand table.

So your brand table will be :

```
id
brand_id //i dont know why you have used this
user_id
brand_quantity
```

And then change your queries with following queries :

```
$userid = YOUR_SESSION_ID;

"SELECT brand_qty FROM brands WHERE brand_id = :id2 and user_id = :userid";

"UPDATE brands SET brand_qty='$s' WHERE brand_id = '$id2' and user_id='$userid'";
```

**SIDE NOTE** : To know more about relation between two tables you can go through this link : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: It still keeps on modifying

Comment: Change your both queries and place user_id in where condition. It should work.

Comment: Still didn't work. Maybe I explained it wrong. the program's system is like that. for example, I have a clothing shop and I just bought fresh new hoodies and I wanted to enter them into the database. That's what `brand_id` is. It contains the input of hoodies and the `brand_qty` is the quantity of hoodies. But if someone else enters the same value 'which is hoodies' the quantity gets updated for all users and that's what I am trying to prevent

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you haven't defined relation yet.